# Terraform attempts to authorize with the wrong AWS region even though AWS CLI seems configured correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, aws-regions

I have the AWS CLI configured correctly such that running `aws sts get-caller-identity` is successful.

I have configured AWS CLI to reach region us-west-2 in a few ways:

```
user ~/ $ echo $AWS_REGION
us-west-2

user ~/ $ echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
us-west-2

user ~/ $ tail ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = us-west-2
```

I have a `main.tf` file with the content:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
  required_version = ">= 0.15"
  required_providers {
    aws = "~> 3.0"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}
```

So that the region is also configured there.

However, `terraform init` keeps failing with:

```
Error: error configuring S3 Backend: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

I used `env TF_LOG=TRACE terraform init` to see what was going on and I can see that the wrong region is being used by terraform:

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=ASIAXDHR3W2BVQFO5BGQ/20230915/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request,  ...
```

note the `us-east-1` there.

How can I get terraform to use the correct region? Is it ignoring my `main.tf` file?

Thanks!

Comment: Weird. Did you try to set the `region = "us-west-2"` in the `s3` configuration block? It should work with the env vars you set, but just to have an idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try a complete block for the backend configuration:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-west-2"
```

}
}

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change things. Terraform is still calling `us-east-1` for the sts command and then it fails.